# Cell reference to non-existent sheet - can't jump to precedent

Tags: excel, xlsb

Slightly odd question, but couldn't find anything on it: I have an .xlsb file in which data is displayed by groups, which have to be selected via a drop down menu, so that only part of the entire data set is displayed at any given time.

I'd like to get the underlying data for all groups, but for some reason the sheet from which it is derived does not exist. That is, I have a `Sheet1` which displays the data, and the cells that hold the data have a formula that says `=Sheet2!A1`, but there is no `Sheet2`, and no sheets are hidden.

What could be going on here? Is this a special .xlsb feature that I don't know about?

Comment: Are any sheets "very hidden"? Do you know how to check for this?

Comment: Sounds intriguing - don't think I've ever heard of this. All I know is that `Unhide sheets` is greyed out, hence my conclusion that there are no hidden sheets...

Comment: Open the VBA editor with ALT+F11. You should see the relevant workbook/worksheet names in a window on the left-hand side. Are there any worksheets listed there which you cannot see?

Comment: There is an .xlam entry, and a VBA project, both of which are password protected... So probably no way to turn this file into anything useful.

Comment: Hmmm. Can't do much about that, I'm afraid. Someone obviously wanted that data hidden!